# How do you implement Model from MVC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, model

This is probably an easy and stupid question but I am at a loss here. Our professor has asked us to create a game ( in my case Sudoku) where we utilize MVC. The view and controller can be used as one js file (since we are getting our feet wet) and model has to be in a separate js file. I am able to get the view working just fine but when I try to use something in the model ... well that is the thing I don't know how to call to the Model file (array or 81 elements containing value to enter into Sudoku grid). Any help, reading, or videos would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use angularJs for two-way binding for MVC

Answer (score 0):

> In Angular applications, the view is the Document Object Model (DOM),
>   the controllers are JavaScript classes, and the model data is stored
>   in object properties.

[AngularJs Learning](https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understand under MVC in Javascript. It is probably wrong.

```js
function Model() {
    this.state=0;
    this.observers=[]
    this.addObserver = function(observer) {
        
        // i, the model, have no idea what this observer is.
        this.observers.push(observer);
    }
    this.notifyObservers = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < this.observers.length; i++) {
            
            // i, the model, have no idea what this does in the observer.
            this.observers[i].modelChanged();
        }
    } 
    this.doSomethingWithInternalState = function(observer){
        this.state+=1
        
        // i, the model will notify observers when my state changes.
        // They can decide on their own what to do then.
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
}

// That would be views (or mini-models or read-only controllers, whatever).
function Observer() {
    this.init = function(model) {
        this.model=model;
    };
    this.modelChanged = function(){
        alert('bazinga');
    };
}

function SudokuBoard(){
    this.boardsize=0;
    this.modelChanged = function() {
        if (this.model.state < 10) {
            this.boardsize=this.model.state*20;
            alert(this.boardsize);
        }
    };
}
SudokuBoard.prototype=new Observer;

function MessageWindow(){
    this.modelChanged = function(){
        alert('Sudoku is cool');
    };
}
MessageWindow.prototype=new Observer;

function AnotherGuiElem(){
    this.bazinga=true;
}
AnotherGuiElem.prototype=new Observer;

// that would be a controller.
document.onclick=function(){
    m.doSomethingWithInternalState();
    a.bazinga=true;
};

// we have a model, views and one controller, now lets connect everything.
var m = new Model;
var b = new SudokuBoard();b.init(m);
var w = new MessageWindow();w.init(m);
var a = new AnotherGuiElem();a.init(m);
m.addObserver(b);
m.addObserver(w);
m.addObserver(a);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```